# C/C++ declare 2D/3D array with ascii art

Tags: c++, c, multidimensional-array, syntax

Long time ago (10+ years) I saw a syntax which let you declare array with "ascii art".

Something like this:

```
//Declares 5x3 2d array
int myArray[] = #####
                #   #
                #####
```

It was even possible to draw a cuboid for 3d arrrays.

My primary language for a very long time is a C++, so I'm sure it was C/C++. My memory tells my that I read about it in some "C++ deprecated features" article, but I doubt this was ever in standard. Maybe it was some kind of a language extension.

It seems that I'm unable to come up with correct words to google it and it bothers me a lot :)

Does anybody has any idea is whether such syntax ever existed in some form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds very much like Eelis' [Multi-Dimensional Analog Literals](http://www.eelis.net/C++/analogliterals.xhtml) (also linked [here](https://isocpp.org/blog/2015/04/analog-literals)). Short example:

```
#include <cassert>

#include "analogliterals.hpp"
using namespace analog_literals::symbols;

int main()
{
    auto l = I---------I;

    auto r = o---------o
             |         !
             !         !
             o---------o;

    assert(l.length == 4);
    assert(r.width == 4 && r.height == 2);
}
```